# How do I make a MySQL query that's equivalent to Fusion Tables "summarize" function?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-fusion-tables

I am parsing a collection of monthly lists of bulletin board systems from 1993-2000 in a city. The goal is to make visualizations from this data. For example, a line chart that shows month by month the total number of BBSes using various kinds of BBS software.

I have assembled the data from all these lists into one large table of around 17,000 rows. Each row represents a single BBS during a single month in time. I know this is probably not the optimal table scheme, but that's a question for a different day. The structure is something like this:

```
date    | name   | phone        | codes | sysop   | speed | software
1990-12 | Aviary | xxx-xxx-xxxx | null  | Birdman | 2400  | WWIV
```

Google Fusion Tables offers a function called "summarize" (or "aggregation" in the older version). If I make a view summarizing by the "date" and "software" columns, then FT produces a table of around 500 rows with three columns: date, software, count. Each row lists the number of BBSes using a given type of software in a given month. With this data, I can make the graph I described above.

So, now to my question. Rather than FT, I'd like to work on this data in MySQL. I have imported the same 17,000-row table into a MySQL database, and have been trying various queries with COUNT and DISTINCT, hoping to return a list equivalent what I get from FT's Summarize function. But nothing I've tried has worked.

Can anyone suggest how to structure such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kirkman, you can do this using a `COUNT` function and the `GROUP BY` statement (which is used in conjunction with aggregate SQL functions)

```
select date, software, count(*) as cnt
from your_table
group by date, software
```